# aChart homescreen widget

Tags: android, bitmap, android-appwidget, achartengine, graphing

I've been trying to get a simple homescreen widget created using aChartEngine as the graphing library, but I can't seem to get the chart to render at all.  There doesn't seem to be any error messages either so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

I have had a chance to see this post (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/achartengine/ovAU5v39ViE) but I can't seem to find this saveToBitmap method to do so.  In the past, I've seen the getDrawingCache method used in AndroidPlot to do the same thing but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the code I'm using to get the chart image:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds)
    {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.myChartView, getChartImage(context));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

private Bitmap getChartImage(Context context)
{
mChartView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        String[] titles = new String[] { "2007", "2008" };
        List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        values.add(new double[] { 5230, 7300, 9240, 10540, 7900, 9200, 12030, 11200, 9500, 10500,
            11600, 13500 });
        values.add(new double[] { 14230, 12300, 14240, 15244, 15900, 19200, 22030, 21200, 19500, 15500,
            12600, 14000 });
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "Monthly sales in the last 2 years", "Month", "Units sold", 0.5,
            12.5, 0, 24000, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
        renderer.setXLabels(1);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Jan");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Mar");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "May");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Jul");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(10, "Oct");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(12, "Dec");
        int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
          seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        }

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,
                Type.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bmp = mChartView.getDrawingCache();
        return bmp;
}
```

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the thing you don't manage to get to work? Display a chart on the screen or save it to a Bitmap?

Comment: Right now, I get a blank widget so I'm not sure where exactly it's failing.  The code for building the chart is directly from their sample code for the native app, and I've just added the mChartView code for enabling the cache and getting the cache.

Comment: Just comment out the first and last 2 lines in your examples and try to run it again.

Comment: Sorry, updated the post with the full code and that I'm pretty new to this.  From what I know, app widgets use RemoteViews and it requires an image to display, so I can't just return the mChartView for the RemoteView (or can I?).